# How to wire RJ12 to db9f modular adaptor?

Tags: serial, communication, rs232, db9

I have a RJ-12 to DB9f modular adapter. There are 6 wires that come out of the adaptor (White, Black, Red, Green, Yellow Blue) - these, as I gather from pin out diagrams, correspond to the 6 jacks of the RJ12. There's also a female connector - with 9 holes. How do I wire the previous wires into the appropriate holes?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no standard for this. You have to copy an adapter known working with your equipment.

Comment: I am using it to program my programmable syringe pump. Is there no way for me to figure this out without having an 'adapter known working with my equipment'.

Comment: (a) I assume that you have an RJ12 socket on this equipment, an RJ12-RJ12 straight-through cable, and this unwired "RJ12-DB9F" adapter (strictly it's probably D**E**9F, but the DB9F name is a common mistake). Is that correct? (b) Adding photos of these parts into your question will help. (c) What did the pump's manufacturer say, when you asked them for help? (d) Are you sure this info isn't in the pump's user manual? (e) Do you have an oscilloscope / logic analyser / multimeter, and experience using it? (f) Your question doesn't say RS-232, but you've used that tag. Are you *sure* it's RS-232?

Comment: (g) Can you open the pump, to view (and take photos of) the components and traces leading to its RJ12 socket?

Comment: @SamGibson sorry for the late reply, but yes - I figured it out by contacting the manufacturer. Thanks!